# overscroll: auto won't work, even with max-height and height set

Tags: html, css

I have a few divs in some other divs, and I want my page height to be constant, so I want to use overflow-y: scroll in my divs so the main wrapper is always 80% of the total height.  As you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/1spverso/), it just makes the page bigger, it doesn't add a scrolling thing (even if it's rendered, it's not usable).

```
#messages_messageUIWrapper {
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    background-color: gray;
    height: 80%;
    max-height: 80%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#messages_contentWrapper {
    display: block;
    background-color: gray;
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% - 260px);
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
#messages_peoplePicker {
    background-color: gray;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 260px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

How can i fix that ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1spverso/1/)**

CSS:

```
html, body { 
    height:100%;
}

#messages_peoplePicker {
    background-color: yellow;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 260px;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

**Edit**: If you want full height, you can use like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1spverso/4/)**

CSS:

```
html, body { 
height:100%;
overflow: hidden;
} 

#messages_messageUIWrapper {
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    background-color: gray;
    overflow: hidden;
    position:absolute; top: 0px; left:0px; right:0px; bottom:0px
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it kind of worked. Kind of. First of all, if I do that, I have a scrollbar (vertical) that appears on my webpage... And second, I wanted to add a div, so it stuck to the bottom of the parent div (in the content div). But I don't know how to do that. Any help ?

Comment: For scroll bar, use this css:  html,body{overflow:hidden;} For 2nd one Can you show us how it will be, without code / demo its difficult to solve :)